# Why this regex is not recognised in my route file from Play 2 project?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want all `.html` files to be redirected to a public folder where they are located so I put this in my `routes` file:

```
GET     /$file<.html>           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/html", file)
```

but it says `Action not found For request 'GET /index.html'`

but I can see it there (when the error appears):

`GET/$file<.html>        controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public/html", file:String)`

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex you specified `<.html>` is only going to match a request that looks like "/ahtml", "/bhtml", "/chtml", or so on since the "." is a single character wildcard.

What you want is something like this, I think:

```
GET   /$file<.*\.html$>      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/html", file)
```

The `.*` is a catch-all for whatever the first part of the file happens to be.

The `\.html$` is what restricts it to html files. Though not strictly necessary, I escaped the dot so it actually matches a period instead of any character.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `*` wildcard:

```
GET     /$file*.html           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/html", file)
```